# How to access IWebHostEnvironment in a Console App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5

A question relative to **.net 5 architecture** decision.

The scenario is this one: I have a multi-tier application with an (web) asp.net (5) application with services and repositories.

I Have a service/helper that has been injecteted [IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment.webrootpath?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IWebHostEnvironment_WebRootPath) to access the path of some files. I need to understand how to Inject this helper or the correct way to do it in the Console Application. the problem is that the console application doesn't have the [ASP.NET Core Web Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0) but only the [Generic One](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

In the service I'm using the [IWebHostEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to access the path of the web application content (because I'm reading and writing files inside there.

What's the correct way to do it?
Many thanks

Comment: you can try like this .https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-do-i-find-which-directory-my-net-core-console-application-was-started-in-or-is-running-from

Comment: and this will give you executing assembly location. var GetDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

Comment: @NAS thanks for replying, yes seems a workaround more than a real solution, and there is no way to inject the object

Comment: @ollie10, please, may you answer this question: The Console Application is invoked by WebApplication in your program flow?

Comment: @AntonioLeonardo no it's a standalone app doing some particular jobs, they share the services and helpers between web app and console app